Magento 2.4.6-p3 - Creating an order programmatically causes errors when adding shipping address to quote
I am trying to create a free order with code, it all works up until adding a shipping address and method, it crashes with errors instead of creating the quote and i can't see why as the code looks fine to me.
Billing address is no problem. I'm just going to provide a small section of the code relating to shipping address:
// add shipping address
            /** @var Address $shippingAddress */
            $shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create();
            $shippingAddress->addData([
                'firstname' => (string)$order->Shipping->FirstName,
                'middlename' => (string)$order->Shipping->MiddleName,
                'lastname' => (string)$order->Shipping->LastName,
                'street' => [(string)$order->Shipping->Street],
                'city' => (string)$order->Shipping->City,
                'postcode' => (string)$order->Shipping->PostCode,
                'telephone' => (string)$order->Shipping->Telephone,
                'country_id' => (string)$order->Shipping->Country,
                'region' => (string)$order->Shipping->Region
            ]);

            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

            $quote->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);

            // add billing address
            /** @var Address $billingAddress */
            $billingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create();
            $billingAddress->addData([
                'firstname' => (string)$order->Billing->FirstName,
                'middlename' => (string)$order->Billing->MiddleName,
                'lastname' => (string)$order->Billing->LastName,
                'street' => [(string)$order->Billing->Street],
                'city' => (string)$order->Billing->City,
                'postcode' => (string)$order->Billing->PostCode,
                'telephone' => (string)$order->Billing->Telephone,
                'country_id' => (string)$order->Billing->Country,
                'region' => (string)$order->Billing->Region
            ]);

            $quote->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);



             // collect all totals
             $quote->collectTotals();

             //$quote->getPayment()->setMethod('free');

            // save the quote
            $this->_cartRepo->save($quote);

this gives me an error:

Call to a member function getStoreId() on null#0
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php(1004):
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address->requestShippingRates()

It seems to be this line in Address.php:
$storeId = $this->getQuote()->getStoreId() ?: $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();


If you need whole working code i will provide you that too.

Use the following data to create a quote and order:
<?php
$order = [
    'currency_id' => 'USD',
    'email' => 'hello@example.com',
    'shipping_address' => ['firstname' => 'John',
        'lastname' => 'Doe',
        'street' => 'xxxxxx',
        'city' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region' => 'xxxxx',
        'postcode' => '85001',
        'telephone' => '52556542',
        'fax' => '3242322556',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1],
    'items' => [
        ['product_id' => '1', 'qty' => 1],
        ['product_id' => '2', 'qty' => 2]]
    ];
?>

The order create function in the module helper file is as follows:
<?php
namespaceYourNameSpace\ModuleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement, \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory, \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository, \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService)
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function createOrder($order)
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($order['email']); // load customet by email address
       if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
            //If not avilable then create this customer
           $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->setStore($store)->setFirstname($order['shipping_address']['firstname'])->setLastname($order['shipping_address']['lastname'])->setEmail($order['email'])->setPassword($order['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote = $this->quote->create(); // Create Quote Object
       $quote->setStore($store); // Set Store
       $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); // Assign quote to Customer

        //add items in quote
       foreach ($order['items'] as $item) {
            $product = $this->product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
        }

        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

       $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
        $quote->save();

        // Set Sales Order Payment
       $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
       $quote->collectTotals()->save();

        // Create Order From Quote
       $orderdata = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

        $orderdata->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if ($orderdata->getEntityId()) {
            $result['order_id'] = $orderdata->getRealOrderId();
        } else {
            $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>

Get all your queries solved. Thank You!

change above code to this will fix your issue,as it is tested
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData([
                'firstname' => (string)$order->Shipping->FirstName,
                'middlename' => (string)$order->Shipping->MiddleName,
                'lastname' => (string)$order->Shipping->LastName,
                'street' => [(string)$order->Shipping->Street],
                'city' => (string)$order->Shipping->City,
                'postcode' => (string)$order->Shipping->PostCode,
                'telephone' => (string)$order->Shipping->Telephone,
                'country_id' => (string)$order->Shipping->Country,
                'region' => (string)$order->Shipping->Region
            ]);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
               
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('pay_cash'); //payment method
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effect inventory
            $quote->save();

    
$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData([
                'firstname' => (string)$order->Billing->FirstName,
                'middlename' => (string)$order->Billing->MiddleName,
                'lastname' => (string)$order->Billing->LastName,
                'street' => [(string)$order->Billing->Street],
                'city' => (string)$order->Billing->City,
                'postcode' => (string)$order->Billing->PostCode,
                'telephone' => (string)$order->Billing->Telephone,
                'country_id' => (string)$order->Billing->Country,
                'region' => (string)$order->Billing->Region
            ]);

